# How to handle duplicate AD usernames from different domain for authentication using ldap proxy + nslcd

Tags: proxy, active-directory, openldap

I have scenario in which there is one ubuntu machine which serves as ldap proxy using ldap as backend and i have two windows machine 2008 r2 having active directory each with different domains
let say **abc.com & xyz.com**.

Both are different, having unique username in each.

But maybe by chance there might be same username in both ad's, say username **test_ad1 in abc.com** & same username **test_ad1 in xyz.com** with different uid/gid in there 
unix attribute tabs in user properties.

So how to handle duplicate users from different AD's for authentication ?

Here is i have tried so far i.e setting correct ldap proxy with nslcd,pam's , i am able to get both AD users respectively i.e by using  **"getent passwd"** command on my ubuntu proxy machine,shows users like

```
test_ad3:*:20001:666:test ad3:/home/test_ad3:/bin/bash      // this users are of ad1 (abc.com)
test_ad4:*:20002:666:test ad4:/home/test_ad4:/bin/bash      // this users are of ad1 (abc.com)
test_ad1:*:20003:666:test ad11:/home/test_ad1:/bin/bash     // this users are of ad1 (abc.com)   password at AD1 is 123@test
test_ad1:*:10010:777:test ad1:/home/test_ad1:/bin/bash      // this users are of ad2 (xyz.com)   password at AD2 is test@1234
test_ad2:*:10011:777:test ad2:/home/test_ad2:/bin/bash      // this users are of ad2 (xyz.com)
```

as we can see all users have different uid/gid i.e they are unique.

So for authentication i tried using indivisual domain name on my ubuntu ldap proxy machine but failed,

```
1) su abc.com\\test_ad1---> auth.log shows me "No passwd entry for user test_ad1"
2) su xyz.com\\test_ad1---> auth.log shows me "No passwd entry for user test_ad1"
```

but when i try only **su test_ad1** & enter password of 1st ad(abc.com) i.e **123@test** than it logon successfully and 
when i enter password of 2nd ad(xyz.com) i.e **test@1234** for same **su test_ad1** than it shows **su: Authentication failure" though password are different** on cli.

I guess because other **test_ad1(10011:777 i.e ad2 user)** comes after **test_ad1(20003:666 i.e ad1 user)**
in **getent passwd** list, this is likely due to sequential working behaviour of **nslcd** i guess,  please correct if wrong.

Here is my slapd.conf

```
################ LDAP MULTIPLE BACK END ##########
######## 1st AD ##########
moduleload     back_ldap
backend        ldap
database       ldap
suffix         "dc=ad2,dc=com"
uri            ldap://192.168.1.189:389/
rebind-as-user
idassert-bind bindmethod=SIMPLE binddn="CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ad2,DC=com" credentials=Admin@1234
#mode=none
idassert-authzFrom "*"
access to * by * read
moduleload rwm.la
overlay rwm
rwm-map attribute uid sAMAccountName
rwm-map attribute homeDirectory unixHomeDirectory
rwm-map objectClass posixAccount person
######## 1st AD ##########

######## 2nd AD ##########
database       ldap
suffix         "dc=ad1,dc=com"
uri            ldap://192.168.1.185:389/
rebind-as-user
idassert-bind bindmethod=SIMPLE binddn="CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ad1,DC=com" credentials=Admin@1234
#mode=none
idassert-authzFrom "*"
access to * by * read
overlay rwm
rwm-map attribute uid sAMAccountName
rwm-map attribute homeDirectory unixHomeDirectory
rwm-map objectClass posixAccount person

######## 2nd AD ##########
```

Here is nslcd.conf

```
# Mappings for Active Directory
pagesize 1000
referrals off
#nss_nested_groups yes

# Passwd
filter passwd (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(objectClass=USER)(!(objectClass=computer))(uidNumber=*))
map   passwd homeDirectory     unixHomeDirectory
map   passwd gecos             displayName
map   passwd gidNumber         primaryGroupID
map   shadow uid               sAMAccountName


# Shadow
filter shadow (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(!(objectClass=computer))(uidNumber=*))
map    shadow shadowLastChange  pwdLastSet

# Groups
filter group (&(objectClass=posixGroup)(gidNumber=*))
#map    group uniqueMember       member

# Local account for nsclcd
uid nslcd
gid openldap

# Where is the LDAP Proxy
#LDAP
uri ldap://192.168.1.186:389  
base dc=ad1,dc=com
base dc=ad2,dc=com

#Note when i change base to reverse order than user test_ad1 logon successfully with ad2 password and ad1 password fails
#base dc=ad2,dc=com
#base dc=ad1,dc=com

base group ou=Groups,dc=ad1,dc=com
base group ou=Groups,dc=ad2,dc=com


# Connect-Account of ad1
binddn cn=administrator,cn=Users,dc=ad1,dc=com
bindpw Admin@1234

# Connect-Account of ad2
binddn cn=administrator,cn=Users,dc=ad2,dc=com
bindpw Admin@1234
```

**Note : I follow [this](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/OpenLDAP_as_proxy_to_AD) document for authenticating ldap proxy to 1 AD.**

I am new to this & i know this might be some confusing !!!

So any LDAP/AD expert out there can help to handle this type of scenario ?

Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone here has face this type of scenario ?

Comment: Your data shows that you don't have a user `abc.com\\test_ad1` but you do have a user `test_ad1`. It would be worth investigating to see why the domain prefix isn't being carried through as part of the identifier as this may be a configurable option.

Comment: yes @roaima that's strange, but i also don't know in detail. How stuff like this work behind the wall :(  .Also for other different domain users `su test_ad2` works `domainname\\test_ad2` doesn't works.